# How to do a x-http request (client) with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to reproduce a x-http request captured with Charles (Web Debugging Proxy) with Python but I can't find any documentation (or don't know what or where to look for).

Comment: Why the `@` prefixes on your dictionary keys? The original doesn't have those.

Comment: Moreover, the request uses JSON, not a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this, as it makes tasks like these easier.

The request you captured seems to be posting JSON data, albeit with a `text/javascript` content type:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript;charset=utf-8')
data = json.dumps({'mod': 'calendar.field', 'action': 'mini', 'vars': {"current": 0}})
r = requests.post('http://www.kavka.be/xhttp.mod', data=data, headers=headers)
```

where `data` is a JSON string created from the same information as your proxy-captured POST.

Alternatively, if you only want to use the standard library, use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
import urllib2
import json

headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript;charset=utf-8')
data = json.dumps({'mod': 'calendar.field', 'action': 'mini', 'vars': {"current": 0}})
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.kavka.be/xhttp.mod', data, headers)
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```